# how can i dynamically keep the quotation marks from this config file?

Tags: python, yaml, config, pyyaml, configparser

```
data: 
    START_DT: '202001'
    END_DT: '202104'
    schema: products
```

i have the above YAML file.

I want to be able to use it such that i get:

```
set START_DT='202001';
set END_DT='202104';
set schema = products
```

notice that the dates are in quotes and the products isn't.

```
with open("data.yml", "r") as ymlfile:
    cfg = yaml.load(ymlfile) 
lines=[]
for k,v in cfg['data'].items():
     print("SET" +' '+  k+'='+ v)
     var = ("SET" +' '+  k+'='+ v)
     lines.append(var)
```

prints:

```
SET START_DT=201901
SET END_DT=202104 
SET SCHEMA=products
```

but now i have lost the quotation marks in the original config for the dates.. how can i retrieve these back?

Answer (score 0):

You could probably find a way to do this in one line or similar, given the flexibility of Python syntax, but I believe there is a cleaner way, which I show below.

```py
import yaml


with open("data.yaml", 'r') as file_:
    config = yaml.safe_load(file_)

lines = []
for key, value in config['data'].items():
    try:
        out = f"SET {key}='{int(value)}';"
    except ValueError:
        out = f"SET {key}={value}"
    print(out)
    lines.append(out)
```

Some things to note: the use of `yaml.load` without a `Loader` should be avoided and will be deprecated as stated and explained [here](https://github.com/yaml/pyyaml/wiki/PyYAML-yaml.load(input)-Deprecation).
Another thing is that for this exact solution to work you need f-strings. If you're on `Python3.7+`, I believe you're good.

The catch here is to use the fact that the dates are only numbers and can be converted to an integer, and that the only entirely numeric fields are dates. **Do note** that if that is not always the case, this solution will render unexpected output.

Moving on: if you can convert the value to an integer, it must be (given the conditions I explained) a date, so you use single quotes and the semi colon at the end (or should the semi colon be in very output?). Else, in which case you won't be able to convert it to an integer, raising `ValueError`, you use the original value without single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

This is part of the YAML spec. Anything that doesn't look like any of the other types, or is quoted, is interpreted as a string.

If you want specific keys to be quoted, when you print them, you could maintain a list of which ones this should happen for.

```py
QUOTED_KEYS = ["START_DT", "END_DT"]

with open("data.yml", "r") as ymlfile:
    cfg = yaml.load(ymlfile) 

lines = []
for k, v in cfg['data'].items():
    if k in QUOTED_KEYS:
        v = f"'{v}'"

    s = f"SET {k}={v}"
    print(s)
    lines.append(s)
```